# LinkedIn share APIs

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I want to use LinkedIn share APIs, but when I use it, it gives me the following unauthorized error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error>
     <status>401</status>
     <timestamp>1290525084519</timestamp>
     <error-code>0</error-code>
     <message>[unauthorized]. OAU: <api token and keys></message>
</error>
```

Any help please?

Comment: Please provide more information. What have you tried? What is the exact error you are getting? What credentials are you using? Do you have an API key (see http://developer.linkedin.com/community/apis)?

Comment: http://developer.linkedin.com/search.jspa;?q=unauthorized

Comment: @m. h. ameen: you might want to delete your comment.  I know Paul asked for credentials, but you shouldn't post such information to the web as it can be used against you.  I went ahead and added the error with the formatting you most likely received to your question.

Comment: This may be a missing "Content-Type" request header. Try setting it to "text/xml" if you send XML. This was my case.

Answer (score 0):

With the PHP tag, you might want to investigate this answer on linked in:
http://developer.linkedin.com/message/3343#3343

It talks about a problem with Zend OAuth and a possible resolution.  I don't know if that is your exact issue, but those forums may be a good place to do some research.